# Singleton template not initializing its instance

Tags: c#, .net, null, initialization, singleton

I have a generic singleton template and a derived class. When the singleton instance is accessed from outside, it returns null. There is nothing wrong that I can spot in the code. In fact while debugging, the static constructor assigns the `_Instance` field. When it comes to the `Instance` property however, the value is null!

**Consumer usage:**

```
var value = Consumer.Instance.SomeProperty;
```

**Singleton template and consumer:**

```
namespace SingletonExample
{
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Reflection;

    public sealed class Consumer:
        Singleton<Consumer>
    {
        private Consumer ()
        {
        }

        public bool SomeProperty { get { return (true); } }
    }

    public abstract class Singleton<T>
        where T: Singleton<T>
    {
        protected Singleton ()
        {
            Singleton<T>.ThrowOnInCompatibleImplementation();
        }

        private static readonly T _Instance = null;

        static Singleton ()
        {
            Singleton<T>.ThrowOnInCompatibleImplementation();

            Singleton<T> _Instance = (T) Activator.CreateInstance(type : typeof(T), nonPublic : true);
        }

        public static T Instance { get { return (Singleton<T>._Instance); } }

        private static void ThrowOnInCompatibleImplementation ()
        {
            if (!typeof(T).IsSealed)
            {
                // Force derived classes to be sealed.
                throw (new InvalidOperationException("Classes derived from [Singleton<T>] must be sealed."));
            }

            if (typeof(T).GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Any())
            {
                // Disallow derived classes to implement static constructors.
                throw (new InvalidOperationException("Classes derived from [Singleton<T>] must not have static constructors."));
            }

            if (typeof(T).GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).Any())
            {
                // Disallow derived classes to implement instance public constructors.
                throw (new InvalidOperationException("Classes derived from [Singleton<T>] must not have public constructors."));
            }

            if (typeof(T).GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Any(ctor => !ctor.IsPrivate))
            {
                // Disallow derived classes to implement instance protected constructors.
                throw (new InvalidOperationException("Classes derived from [Singleton<T>] must not have protected constructors."));
            }

            if (!typeof(T).GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Any())
            {
                // Force derived classes to implement a private parameterless constructor.
                throw (new InvalidOperationException("Classes derived from [Singleton<T>] must have a private parameterless constructor."));
            }

            if (typeof(T).GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Any(ctor => ctor.GetParameters().Length != 0))
            {
                // Force derived classes to implement a private parameterless constructor.
                throw (new InvalidOperationException("Classes derived from [Singleton<T>] must have a private parameterless constructor."));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Although I am very open to suggestions on improving the implementation, there are already tons of questions on SO regarding such templates, thread safety and good/bad practices. Would appreciate any hints as to what is going wrong here.

Comment: Some people would say that a Singleton in itself is a bad practice or "anti-pattern". Are you sure you actually need a Singleton? Would the world end if anyone ever happened to create a second consumer? What about unit tests? They will become next to impossible with a singleton.

Comment: That's not the question but to answer yours, I personally use these as data containers for read-only application wide properties. The usage does not warrant unit tests to begin with. Beyond that, any more background is too subjective to explain here. Do you see a problem with the code though? I can't seem to spot it.

Comment: Personally, I think you want global variables and Singleton is a way you can have their side effect (global variable) and still say it's a pattern, it's good coding. It's not. A singleton is a code smell. You should probably use injection and have proper unit tests. But it's *your* code, you will know what's best, refer to the answer for the technical problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Singleton<T> _Instance = (T) Activator.CreateInstance(type : typeof(T), nonPublic : true);
```

should be

```
_Instance = (T) Activator.CreateInstance(type : typeof(T), nonPublic : true);
```

Comment: Holy mother of goose! I just noticed that typo. How does that code even compile without the dot separator? I changed it to `Singleton<T>._Instance = ...` and it works fine now.

Comment: I would have expected a warning about variable hiding as well, but I don't have compiler here to check.

Comment: Thanks. This has got me my worst SO blooper.